# Android convert audio /voice mail file to text file

Tags: android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, cmusphinx

As in android 4.1 and above speech to text library included in android library itself .I want to recognition on voice mail/sound file into text file  using Google library or any other third party library.I have seen link to use dragon naturally speaking and CMU Sphinx but not found any example to use this in android.I will prefer to use Google library for speech recognition .Please suggest any way to do this.